# Tag wikis for wide angle and ultra wide angle

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

Hey @Imre — I approved your tag wiki edits for [wide-angle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wide-angle) and [ultra-wide-angle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra-wide-angle) since there was nothing at all there before, but, citation needed on your sensor-size-related definitions. Sounds plausible but I'd like to see a reference, and maybe an update to:

[What is an ultra-wide lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/327/what-is-an-ultra-wide-lens)

Answer (score 1):

I think I heard this first at an open university photography course some years ago (a real one, not the [imaginary one that gives me hard assignments](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16460/4390)). I don't even remember the name of my mentor there, so I can't pass this as a reference. Wikipedia seems to agree, but cannot be used as a credible reference by itself and is missing citation also.

I added link to our [relevant question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/327/what-is-an-ultra-wide-lens) into those tag wiki bodies, and will add my answer there when I find some better references.